# Can't access session variables between 2 files

Tags: php, session

I'm unable to access my session variables even with `session_start()` on both files.

File1.php

```
<?php
  session_start();

  ...

  if($responseCode == 1) {
    $_SESSION['card_id']    = $_POST['card_id'];
    $_SESSION['password']   = $_POST['password'];
    print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
    print 'window.location = "http://domain.com/File2.php";';
    print '</script>';
  }
?>
```

File2.php

```
<?php
  session_start();

  $account = getAccount();

  echo "document.write('$account')";

  function getAccount() {
    $card_id = $_SESSION['card_id'];
    $string = "card = " . $card_id ;
    return $string;
  }
?>
```

File1.php does a curl request and, if it succeeds, it redirects to File2.php. However, I only see `card :` without the card_id I entered.

Comment: First, make sure that you actually set the session variables (are you 100% sure that $responseCode is indeed 1 and your script does get to that part?)

Comment: Yes I'm sure because the redirection works. I can also do a `var_dump($_SESSION)` instead of the redirection and I can see both values.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about this, but try using window.location.href instead of just window.location. I think i had similar issue with sessions, give it a shot.

Comment: I tried with `window.location.href` instead but I'm still having the issue. The redirection works but I have no access to those session variables.

Comment: Check the first url, that of file1.php. Is it set to `http://www.domain.com/File1.php`? Then the session will not be valid if you redirect to `http://domain.com/File2.php`, which is without www. You need to use mod_rewrite to ensure your url aways has www.

Comment: @coderkane It works! I had no idea the www would make that difference. The page works with the www or not but I need them if I want access to those variables. If you want to post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because the www is considered a subdomain, and hence the session does not persist. You can fix this in 2 ways -

1. Which I consider is the better way, to use htaccess to redirect all non www urls to www urls, which is better for SEO
2. Check the PHP manual on how to [set session across multiple subdomains.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)

[This post explains](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/295576/strange-php-session-problem) how www is considered a subdomain, if you are curious.